# How to Generate a New Random Number Once Every time Content View Loads?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

The intent here is generate a new random number every time MyView loads while keeping that randomly generated number unaffected with any MyView refresh. However, none of the approaches below work. I will explain each approach and its outcome. Any ideas on how to properly accomplish what I am asking?

**Approach #1:** I assumed a new number is generated every time MyView loads. However, a random number is generated once for the entire app lifetime.  I placed a button to force a view refresh, so when I press the button a new random number should not generate, which is what happens. *What is wrong with this approach?*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
        
            NavigationLink(destination: MyView()) {
                Text("Link to MyView")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

    @State var randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100)
    @State var myMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        Text(String(randomInt))

        Button("Press Me") { 
            myMessage = String(randomInt)
        }

        Text(myMessage)
    }

}
```

**Approach #2:** I tried to update randomInt variable via let inside the Body but this generates a new random number every time the button is pressed (which is forcing a view refresh). Again, not the intended outcome. *What is wrong with this approach?*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
        
            NavigationLink(destination: MyView()) {
                Text("Link to MyView")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

    @State var randomInt = 0
    @State var myMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        
        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100)
        
        Text(String(randomInt))

        Button("Press Me") { 
            myMessage = String(randomInt)
        }

        Text(myMessage)

    }

}
```

**Approach #3:**  The idea here to pass a new randomly generated integer every time the "Link to MyView" is pressed. I assumed that Int.Random is ran and passed every time Content View loads. However, a random number is only generated the first-time the entire app runs. *What is wrong with this approach?*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
        
            NavigationLink(destination: MyView(randomInt: Int.random(in: 1...100))) {
                Text("Link to MyView")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

    @State var randomInt = 0
    @State var myMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(myMessage)

        Button("Press Me") { 
            myMessage = String(randomInt)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach #1:

`MyView` is created once, when `ContentView` renders.

Inside `MyView`, `randomInt` is set when the view is first created and then never modified. When you press the button, `myMessage` is set, but `randomInt` is never changed. If you wanted `randomInt` to change, you'd want to say something like:

```
randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100)
```

inside your button action:

#### Approach #2:

You're creating a *new* `randomInt` variable in the local scope by declaring `let randomInt =` inside the view body.

Instead, if I'm reading your initial question correctly, I think you'd want something using `onAppear`:

```
struct MyView: View {

    @State var randomInt = 0
    @State var myMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(randomInt))

            Button("Press Me") {
                myMessage = String(randomInt)
            }

            Text(myMessage)
        }.onAppear {
            randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100)
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see that with this, every time you go back in the navigation hierarchy and then revisit MyView, there's a new value (since it appears again). The button triggering a re-render doesn't re-trigger `onAppear`

#### Approach #3:

`MyView` gets created on the first render of the parent view (`ContentView`). Unless something triggers a refresh of `ContentView`, you wouldn't generate a new random number here.

---

In conclusion, I'm a little unclear on what the initial requirement is (what does it mean for a View to 'load'? Does this just mean when it gets shown on the screen?), but hopefully this describes each scenario and maybe introduces the idea of `onAppear`, which seems like it might be what you're looking for.

---

Addendum: if you want the random number to be generated only when `ContentView` loads (as the title says), I'd create it in `ContentView` instead of your `MyView` and pass it as a parameter.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: MyView(randomInt: $randomInt)) {
                Text("Link to MyView")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @Binding var randomInt : Int
    @State var myMessage: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(String(randomInt))
        
        Button("Press me to refresh only myMessage") {
            myMessage = String(randomInt)
        }
        
        Button("Press me to change the randomInt as well") {
            randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100)
            myMessage = String(randomInt)
        }
        
        Text(myMessage)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, when the view is shown on the screen is what I wanted to say about 'loading' a view. I believe the OnAppear event is what I am looking for. I somehow overlooked this. Thanks! I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I work on a way that always make a new random, your problem was you just used initialized State **over and over! Without changing it.**

*Maybe the **most important** thing that you miss understood was using a State wrapper and expecting it performance as computed property, as you can see in your 3 example all has the same issue in different name or form! So for your information **computed property** are not supported in SwiftUI until Now! That means our code or us should make an update to **State Wrappers**, and accessing them like you tried has not meaning at all to them.*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
        
            NavigationLink(destination: MyView()) {
                Text("Link to MyView")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var randomInt: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let unwrappedRandomInt: Int = randomInt { Text(unwrappedRandomInt.description) }
        
        Button("Press Me") { randomMakerFunction() }
            .onAppear() { randomMakerFunction() }
        
    }
    
    func randomMakerFunction() { randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...100) }
    
}
```